# %1 in batch file not regestering in windows 10

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file for an installer of a file type. The problem is that whenever I run the batch file the %1 disappears and is not applied to ftype. Instead, it is left with just the quotes. Here is the code.

```
@echo off

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
    IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "amd64" (
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\config\system"
) ELSE (
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
)

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params= %*
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params:"=""%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------    

assoc .beest=beestTest
ftype beestTest="C:\BeestFileType\TextEditor.exe" -f "%1" %*
pause
```

Here is the output that does not show %1 for some reason.

```
.beest=beestTest
beestTest="C:\BeestFileType\TextEditor.exe" -f ""
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: How do you call the batch file?

Comment: IExpress the installer compiler I am using has a run batch file option during install.

Comment: According to the comment on harrymc's answer, you have not yet called IExpress. So that invalidates the above comment. Again, how do you call the batch file to not get this result? are you doubleclicking it? are you executing it from command line? If so, what is the exact command you are executing? It seems to be going wrong somewhere in how the batch file is being called.

Comment: You can simplify your permissions check by instead just using... `openfiles>nul 2>&1` then `if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (goto UACPrompt )`

Comment: Also, you are using `pushd "%CD%"`, however the "current directory" is affected by how the script is called/run. If you put echo `%CD%` in the file `C:\temp\test.bat` and double click to run it will echo `C:\temp\ `. But, if you open cmd and are in `C:\windows\system32\ ` and rather than navigate to the script location you just type its full path and hit enter like `C:\Windows\System32> C:\temp\test.bat` then the `%CD%` will instead echo `C:\Windows\System32\ `. So where ever possible, use `%~dp0`to refer to the script's actual path.

Comment: In addition to the above, beware of trying to use the `%~dp0` modifier for this purpose from within a subroutine or if the batch using this modifier was called from another batch, as it will no longer expand as the path for the running batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my solution was to have %%1 instead of %1 because double percents have it display % instead of look for a parameter.

Comment: This means that you are parsing the batch file twice. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that the batch file is being executed by `command.com`,
not by `cmd.exe`. IExpress is after all a very ancient product, dating from the
early beginning of Windows (I cannot really recommend its use).

You need to execute the batch file explicitly in IExpress using `cmd`,
a modern command interpreter, like this:

```
cmd.exe /c file.bat argument
```

Comment: I will try this but the problem is that I have not used IExpress yet and just launched the batch file. So I do not know if adding it to IExpress will fix it.